# How would I undo something in the python turtle module with a key press?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How would I undo something in the python turtle module?

Here is my code:

```
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(undo, "ctrl + z") # You can't combine ctrl + z, so how do I do this?
```

Comment: `turtle` is built on top of `tkinter` and with the latter, a control-z can be specified with `"<Control-KeyPress-H>"`.

Comment: so how would you include that in code, can I have a code example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `"<Control-KeyPress-z>"` — but @cdlane corrected that and took the idea further.

Answer (score 2):

> turtle is built on top of tkinter and with the latter, a control-z can
> be specified with "<Control-KeyPress-z>".

As stated by @martineau (+1) but with a minor correction of 'H' -> 'z'.

You can't do it with the functions that turtle provides.  Python turtle doesn't pass key press symbols directly onto tkinter, it appends 'KeyPress-' onto them. So if you did the obvious:

```
screen.onkeypress(do_it, 'Control-z')
```

it will pass 'KeyPress-Control-z' instead of 'Control-KeyPress-z'.  So we need to whip up a little function of our own:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def oncontrolkeypress(self, fun, key):
    def eventfun(event):
        fun()

    self.getcanvas().bind("<Control-KeyPress-%s>" % key, eventfun)

def do_it():
    turtle.circle(100)

def undo_it():
    turtle.undo()

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onkeypress(do_it, 'c')
oncontrolkeypress(screen, undo_it, 'z')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Type 'c' to draw a circle.  Type a control 'z' to undraw it.

To keep it simple, I've left off the usual features of a turtle key binding function where you can pass `None` for the key to bind all control keys and pass `None` for the function to unbind the key.

Comment: Hi cdlane, I like the way you explained it but is there also a way to type 'control + z'

Comment: @SkCoder: You could modify the `oncontrolkeypress()` function to accept any arguments in any format you want — as long as they get translated into terms that the underlying `tkinter` module understands with respect to the binding of callback functions to different types of keyboard "events".

Comment: @cdlane: Couple of observations. The OP is using turtle's `onkey()` function, which is equivalent to `onkeyrelease()`, not `onkeypress()`. Secondly, I think it would be better to have a more generic function where the contents of the `key` string argument is used to indicate whether it's a control key or not — along the lines of what the OP asked in their above comment (similar to how the tkinter widget `bind()` function works using "[Event modifiers](https://web.archive.org/web/20190516175312id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-modifiers.html)").