# Does turtle something like a Ctrl-Z (Undo) function?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, undo, python-turtle

I'm trying to code an whiteboard program so I need to have something like <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> (Undo) function in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There IS an undo function called (*drumroll*) `undo()` !

Ex: `turtle.undo()`

Apparently the number of Undos is limited by the UndoBuffer.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-undo-function-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Like pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65398629/13552470) great answer, there is a handy `undo` function built into `turtle`.

To elaborate, here is the `turtle.undo` function's documentation that can be accessed through `print(help(turtle.undo))` or `print(turtle.undo.__doc__)`:

> `undo()`
>
> undo (repeatedly) the last turtle action.
>
> No argument.
>
> undo (repeatedly) the last turtle action.
> Number of available undo actions is determined by the size of
> the undobuffer.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>    >>> for i in range(4):
>    ...     fd(50); lt(80)
>    ...
>    >>> for i in range(8):
>    ...     undo()
>    ...
> ```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63433353/13552470) answer for the implementation.