# is there a way to reverse a turtle movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle, python-3.11

so ive got some code that makes it in a random direction and i want it to have borders

```
nextpos = [
        (turtle.xcor() + 50, turtle.ycor()),
        (turtle.xcor() - 50, turtle.ycor()),
        (turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor() + 50),
        (turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor() - 50)
    ]
    rnextpos = random.randint(0,3)
    turtle.goto(nextpos[rnextpos])
```

this is the code and the idea ive had is to just have this

```
nextpos = [
        (turtle.xcor() - 50, turtle.ycor()),
        (turtle.xcor() + 50, turtle.ycor()),
        (turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor() - 50),
        (turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor() + 50)
    ]
    turtle.goto(nextpos[rnextpos])
```

but it doesnt seem to work not sure why
any ideas?

Comment: Given a prior move, do you want to undo just it, or do you want to keep track of all moves to undo more than one?

Comment: just 1 move thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`undo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.undo)? Can you provide context for the application you're creating? What does "not working" entail exactly? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ggorlen `undo()`  is perfect if the OP wants to effectively erase the prior line draw. Great recommendation!

Comment: No problem. Possibly related: [How would I undo something in the python turtle module with a key press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431581/how-would-i-undo-something-in-the-python-turtle-module-with-a-key-press)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just keep track of the current position by setting it to a variable. Then you can calculate a new position variable using your code. The goto with the new position can be reversed by a goto the the current position.

This should goto and then undo a bunch of times.

```py
import turtle
import random
import time

def get_random_move(current_position, distance=50):
    next_position = list(current_position)
    index = random.choice([0,1]) ## x or y
    dist = random.choice([distance, -distance]) ## plus or minus
    next_position[index] += dist
    return next_position

for _ in range(10):
    current_position = turtle.pos()
    next_position = get_random_move(current_position)

    time.sleep(0.5)
    turtle.goto(next_position)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    turtle.goto(current_position)
```